# Seeking common interface for ST_Geometry SDO_Geomtry

Tags: postgis, java, oracle-spatial

I've worked a fair bit with Oracle Spatial and I've had some requests to transition to PostgreSQL Spatial.

Is there a common interface for SDO_Geometry and ST_Geometry?  I'm working in Java with EclipseLink ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoTools http://geotools.org provides PostGIS and OracleSpatial datastores which will abstract away the differences.

Answer (score 2):

[OGR](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html#vector-programs) supports both Oracle Spatial and PostGIS and there are Java bindings for OGR. Maybe OGR's ogr2ogr can help.